# Reading xml response from ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml

I would like to read name and id from the following xml code which is coming from ajax request 
and convert to a table. I dont know how to parse xml or read it. Can anyone kindly help me ?

```
<pre>
  <ConversionResult xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/invoicerRESTapi.Controllers">
    <Id>0</Id>
    <Result>0</Result>
    <lesson_details_list xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
    <d2p1:string>anik</d2p1:string>
    <d2p1:string>1</d2p1:string>
    <d2p1:string>manik</d2p1:string>
    <d2p1:string>2</d2p1:string>
    <d2p1:string>fnametest</d2p1:string>
    <d2p1:string>3</d2p1:string>
    <d2p1:string i:nil="true"/>
    <d2p1:string>4</d2p1:string>
    <d2p1:string>jamal</d2p1:string>
    <d2p1:string>5</d2p1:string>
    </lesson_details_list>
    <month i:nil="true"/>
    </ConversionResult>
</pre>
```

### EDIT 1 (CLIENT CODE)

```
    function displayCustomer() {

        $.ajax({

            url: "http://localhost:31517/customer",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "xml",

        }.then(function (xml) {
            var doc = $(xml.documentElement);
            doc.find("lesson_details_list *").each(function (index, el) {
                console.log($.trim(el.textContent))
            })
        })

        );

    }
```

### Edit 2

#### basic.js

function displayCustomer() {

```
$.ajax({

    url: "http://localhost:31517/customer",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "xml",

}.then(function (xml) {
    var doc = $(xml.documentElement);
    doc.find("lesson_details_list *").each(function (index, el) {
        console.log($.trim(el.textContent))
    })
})

);
```

}

#### Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Client Api for consuming REST service</title>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.12.3.js"></script>
    <script src="js/basic.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="customer_table">

    </table>

</body>
</html>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    displayCustomer();
});
</script>
```

Edit 3:

#### Solved

Working code

```
function displayCustomer() {

        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:31517/customer",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "xml"
        }).then(function (xml) {
            var doc = $(xml.documentElement);
            doc.find("lesson_details_list *").each(function (index, el) {
                console.log($.trim(el.textContent))
            })
        })

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "read name"? What is expected result?

Comment: <d2p1:string>manik</d2p1:string>
    <d2p1:string>2</d2p1:string>
manik is  name
2 is the id

how can i read them? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define `documentElement` of returned `xml` as jQuery object variable; call `.find()` chained to `documentElement` jQuery object with selector `"lesson_details_list *"` to select child nodes of `lesson_details_list` element `.each()` to iterate child nodes of `lesson_details_list` , `.textContent` to return text within child nodes of `lesson_details_list`

```
$.ajax(/* settings */)
.then(function(xml) {
  var doc = $(xml.documentElement);
  doc.find("lesson_details_list *").each(function(index, el) {
    console.log($.trim(el.textContent))
  })
})
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/6gke3432/2/

Comment: Alternatively, using `.filter()` to select `<d2p1:string>` elements https://jsfiddle.net/6gke3432/4/

Comment: hi bro, Please check my edit. i added my client code..i cant get it to work..it says 
Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value).then is not a functiondisplayCustomer @ basic.js:10(anonymous function)

Comment: @NurulAlamAnik Syntax error at `$.ajax()` call; missing closing `)` before `.then()` ; extra `)` before closing `}` of `displayCustomer`. Try adjusting to `function displayCustomer() {

        $.ajax({

            url: "http://localhost:31517/customer",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "xml"

        }).then(function (xml) {
            var doc = $(xml.documentElement);
            doc.find("lesson_details_list *").each(function (index, el) {
                console.log($.trim(el.textContent))
            })
        })

    }`

Comment: It doesnt return anything on console. I added my code in Edit 2 section.. :( I am probably making some silly mistakes...please kindly check

Comment: @NurulAlamAnik Why are you wrapping script text and an entire `.html` document with `<pre></pre>` tags ? Also `<script>` at `Index.html` is outside of closing `</html>` tag?

Comment: oh i thought thats how we are suppose to add code in stack over flow...in pre tag...i see i made a silly mistake in my code..i will test it again..sorry

Comment: I was able to use your solution. It worked. Thanks for your kind help :) I edited the post with working code at the bottom